# Lambda editing Nth object of list and return edited list

Tags: python, list, lambda, map-function

I have a list a.

```
a = [[10,13,14],[34,23,4],[1,6,3]]
```

Now I want to increase the Nth integer of each sublist in the list.

```
def increase(sublistOrg):
    sublist = sublistOrg.copy()
    sublist[1] += 1
    return sublist

aEdited = list(map(increase, a))
```

Can I replace the additional "increase" function with a lambda expression?

Comment: This modifies the initial list inplace and assigns it to an additional. Is that intentional and a requirement, or is creating a new list also fine?

Answer (score 1):

```
lambda x: [x[i] + 1 if i == 1 else x[i] for i in range(len(x))]
```

This works, but it's probably worse than just using a "normal" function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a lambda but it's probably uglier than the solution you have:

```
aEdited = list(map(lambda x: [element if index != 1 else element + 1 for index, element in enumerate(x)], a))
```